# c# game have multiple icons resolution?

Tags: c#

How can I make my games developed in c# having multiple icons? (same picture with different resolutions), so, after installing it, and going to start-->games, and change your view, the resolution will be adapted to the right size.
Thx in advanced

Answer (score 7):

The [ICO format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) can contain images for several resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use your favorite search engine for the keywords `multi resolution icons`.